# make text float right of a javascript slider gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider, css-float

I am using a wordpress plugin called Slideshow gallery and would like to float the text that I have below it so that it appears next to the gallary on the right hand side.

I have tried the following:

```
.bioText{
font-size: 14px;
font-size: 1.428571429rem;
line-height: 1.2;
font-weight: normal;
}
.nextToPic{
float:left;
padding: 0px 15px 10px 15px;
display:block;
}
```

but it does not seem to work, any help?

this is the site I am workig on http://thestudentbubble.com/hidden-gems/hidden-gems-restaurants/hub-box/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left` to `.slideshow-wrapper`, and remove float from `.nextToPic`, and also you can apply some margins to `.slideshow-wrapper`.

Comment: the margins don't seem to be working - I tried padding too :/

Comment: `margin: 0 20px 20px 0;` just tested in Firefox and Chrome and it works.

Comment: I have this in the css - '.slideshow-wrapper{
float:left;
margin: 0 20px 20px 0;}'  Howeer if you look at the website it doesnt have the margins, it is still very crampped. Thank you for your help by the way - really appreciate it.

Comment: Use it on `#slideshow-wrappergallery1` id, or use `!important` clause `.slideshow-wrapper{ margin: 0 20px 20px 0 !important }`, id attribute has higher priority than class attribute.

Comment: perfect - Thank you !! And thank you for the clarifyng the difference between ID and class prioritiess :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.nextToPic{
    float:right;
    padding: 0px 15px 10px 15px;
    display:block;
    direction:rtl;
}
```

Comment: Dosen't work unfortunatlly - you can see the result on the website